# Show a java console menu again after switch finishes

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java console menu but i can't render it in the console. Here is the code i wrote so far.

```
package com.registrar;

import java.util.*;

class GUIMenu {
private Course[] courses = new Course[100];
private Person[] persons = new Person[1000];

public void display_menu() {
  System.out.println("****************MENU*****************");
  System.out.println("[1] Add Course\n[2] Add Student to Course \n[3] Verify Registration \n[4] Remove Student \n[5] Add Persons");
  System.out.println("**************************************");
  System.out.println("Selection: ");
}

public GUIMenu(){
Person p = null;
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
int input = in.nextInt();

switch (input){
  case 1:
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Course Name: ");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Course ID:");
    Integer cID = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Instructor ID:");
    Integer pn = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < persons.length; i ++){
        System.out.println(persons[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<persons.length; i++){
        if(persons[i] !=null){
            if(persons[i].getId().intValue() == pn){
                System.out.println("Record Found");
                p  = persons[i];
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Record Not Found");
        }
    }
    Course c = new Course(name, cID);
    if(p!=null){
        Instructor ins = new Instructor(p);
        c.setInstructor(ins);
    }
    System.out.println(c + " has been created");

    for(int i = 0; i < courses.length; i ++){
        if(courses[i] == null){
            courses[i] = c;
            break;
        }
    }
    new GUIMenu();
  case 2:
      for(int i = 0; i < courses.length; i ++){
          if(courses[i] != null)
              System.out.println(courses[i]);
      }
      break;
  case 3:
    System.out.println ( "You picked option 3" );
    break;
  case 4:
    System.out.println ( "You picked option 4" );
    break;
  case 5:
      Scanner pers = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter Person Name: ");
      String pname = pers.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter Person ID:");
      Integer oiID = pers.nextInt();
      Person per = new Person(pname, oiID);
      for(int i = 0; i < persons.length; i ++){
        if(persons[i] == null){
            persons[i] = per;
            break;
        }
      }
      display_menu();
  default:
    System.err.println("Unrecognized option");
}
}

public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    GUIMenu a = new GUIMenu();
    a.display_menu();
}
}
```

I am trying that after a selection on the menu the code returns the menu again after completing the code associated with that particular selection. What i am doing wrong? I dont see the menu at all displaying.

Comment: yes yes it was a mistake already removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What i am doing wrong?

Look at the code: This is where it starts:

```
public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    GUIMenu a = new GUIMenu();  // This is executed first...
    a.display_menu();
}
```

let's have a look at it

```
public GUIMenu(){
    Person p = null;
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    int input = in.nextInt(); // this is where it's waiting for your input.
    ...
```

Looking at the flow of your code, it is pretty clear why the menu is not shown.

**EDIT:**

You are looking for something like this:

```
public void runApplication() {
    // init Scanner
    boolean nextRound = true;
    while(nextRound) {
        displayMenu();
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        switch(input) {
            case 1: // do stuff
                break;
            case 2: // this is the exit command
                nextRound = false;
                break;
            // more cases
            default:
                // undefined input
        }
    }
}
```

So you use your constructor only for constructor relevant code and later call the `runApplication()` method.

Comment: Ohh so its waiting for the input and that second line never executes.

Comment: that second line will execute, once the constructor call (line 1) is finished. Also, you forgot the `break` at the end of case 1 and 5.

Comment: and calling `new GUIMenu();` within the `GUIMenu` constructor makes no sense at all. You will call the constructor, but not save a reference to the created object.

Comment: jlordo Thanks, you put me in the right direction. I have the menu showing up, the only thing now is how to show the menu once the code in selection 5 let's say has finished executing?

Comment: @KleonKita: If I were you, I'd put only code that's necessary for creating an object in the constructor. Erverything else can be handled in your method. To show your menu, once the it's done, you need to use a `while` loop.

Comment: Do u have an example i can use cuse i really dont understand how to show the menu again. Do you mean a while loop inside the case code?

Comment: @KleonKita: The other way around: the `while` loop around your `switch` statement.